# How add products to opportunity in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components

How to add products to opportunity product list when a particular opportunity selects the product by checking the checkbox. I have used LWC to display all the products . so Now I need to pass all the products to opportunity product list. how can I achieve this??

.js (The below code fetching all the Id's of selected proudcts by a particular opportunity)

these product Id's should be added to that particular opportunty.

```js
var el = this.template.querySelector('lightning-datatable');

var selected = el.getSelectedRows();

let selectedIdsArray = [];

for (const element of selected) {
    console.log('elementid', element.Id);
    selectedIdsArray.push(element.Id);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to create OpportunityLineItems for selected products?

Comment: yes @ShagunSharma....i have writen some code for that..but its shwing some error while deplyoing....if u have solution please do share

Comment: could you please post what error you are getting.

Comment: @ShagunSharma ivalid type :Opportunity_Product__C this what i am getting error..while creating new Opportunity_Product__C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create  Opportunity_Product__c records then you can do something like below code example:

.JS File

```
funName(){
   var selected = el.getSelectedRows();
   var  oppProductList= [];
   for(var i in selected){
     oppProductList.push({
        Opportunity__c: {opportunityId},
        Product__c: selected[i].Id,
       {someotherCustomField}: {value},
    });
  }
   yourApexMethod({oppProduct: JSON.stringify(oppProductList)})
     .then((reponse) = >{
        //do something
     })
     .catch((error) = >){
        //do something
     });
}
```

Note: Make sure to import the apex controller method in your LWC .js file.

Apex:

```
public class className{
   @AuraEnabled
   public static void createOpportunityProduct(String oppProduct){
      List<Opportunity_Product__c> oppProductList=(List<Opportunity_Product__c>) System.JSON.deserialize(oppProduct, List<Opportunity_Product__c>.Class);
      if(!oppProductList.isEmpty()){
          insert oppProductList;
       }
   }
}
```

Hope this will help you :)